# Get the category information for an album using spotipy?

Tags: python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

I am just trying to get genres for all Talking Heads albums, using some sample code. However, none of the objects returned have a `categories` or `genre` field. How would I go about doing that?

```
# Source
# https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/examples/artist_albums.py

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('artist_albums')
logging.basicConfig(level='INFO')

def get_artist(name):
    results = sp.search(q='artist:' + name, type='artist')
    items = results['artists']['items']
    if len(items) > 0:
        return items[0]
    else:
        return None


def show_artist_albums(artist):
    albums = []
    results = sp.artist_albums(artist['id'], album_type='album')
    albums.extend(results['items'])
    while results['next']:
        results = sp.next(results)
        albums.extend(results['items'])
    seen = set()  # to avoid dups
    albums.sort(key=lambda album: album['name'].lower())
    for album in albums:
        name = album['name']
        if name not in seen:
            logger.info('ALBUM: %s', name)
            seen.add(name)
    return albums
            
artist = get_artist("Talking Heads")
albums = show_artist_albums(artist)

# Get album object
sample_album = albums[0]
sample_album_dets = sp.albums([sample_album['id']])
```

Answer (score 0):

Albums don't have genres, only an artist has a genres field.